# serving static files with plumber package - files not found (404)

Tags: r, plumber

I want to serve a static file with [`plumber`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plumber/index.html) as described [here](http://plumber.trestletech.com/docs/static/). The file with the routes etc. is `server.R`:

```
#* @get /files
function()
{
  return(dir("files"))
}

#* @static ./files
list()
```

This should make the `files` directory available on the path `/public`. Inside `files` there is a file `index.html`. Running above code:

```
library(plumber)
r <- plumb("server.R")
r$run()
```

Calling `localhost:8000/files` returns:

```
["index.html"]
```

However, calling `localhost:8000/public/index.html` gives a 404 error:

```
{"error":["404 - Resource Not Found"]}
```

Printing the `r` object, the public path appears to be defined:

```
> r
<plumber>
  Public:
    addAssets: function (dir, path = "/public", options = list()) 
    ...
```

**Any ideas where I go wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

Mea culpa... I silently renamed the annotation for static file servers and (apparently) never updated the docs.

I added a working example here: https://github.com/trestletech/plumber/tree/master/inst/examples/05-static , but the new annotation is `@assets`, not `@static`. I'll update the docs shortly.